# How to validate string attributes avoiding "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Data too long for column [...]" exception?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm facing a problem with MySQL text columns related to string attributes containing UTF-8 characters. Let's suppose we have a migration like this one:

```
class CreateItems < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create :items do |t|
      t.text "description", null: false
    end
  end
end
```

As we know the maximum length of the `MySQL` `TEXT` column is 65535 bytes, and adding a validation like this one below should prevent such `MySQL` exception:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :description, length: { maximum: 65535 }
end
```

And of course it works up to the moment when a user puts a very long text containing some characters that are more than 1 byte long. How is the difference? See the example:

```
> s = "A text with some national characters ĄąĘę"          
=> "A text with some national characters ĄąĘę"
> s.length
=> 41
> s.bytesize
=> 45
```

So e.g. if somebody puts a long description 65500 character long with lots of such characters, validation passes it but MySQL does not forgive...

Temporarily I've created a `bytesize` validation:

```
class BytesizeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    record.errors.add(attribute, :too_long, count: options[:maximum]) if value.bytesize > options[:maximum]
  end
end
```

which used in the model as follows:

```
validates :description, bytesize: { maximum: 65535 }
```

solves my problem but I believe, that there is a simple solution. Maybe I missed something and it is possible to make regular Rails `length validation` covering multibyte characters as expected here?

I use Rails 4.2.5.1, Ruby 2.2.4 and MariaDB 15.1 on Linux.